# how to add month for apa6 style in bibtex @inproceedings entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style, cv, apa6

I'm building my CV in latex and I need to add conference presentations in apa6 style. The only problem is that the output does not include the (year, month) format, which is required for the apa6 style.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Waltzsy2006implicit,
author = {Waltz, C},
title = {\emph{Implicit Attitude Assessments}},
address = {Paper presented at the..., Chicago, IL},
year = {2006},
month = {November},
}
```

This is the resulting output:
[image]

I tried to solve this problem by adding the month to the year field

```
year = {2006, November},
```

which only apparently fixed the problem, because when I added another citation with the same month, then it added a "a" and "b" at the end the month:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how deactivate the "a..." function or add the month to the year field to meet the apa6 standard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should fix your database (i.e., remove those the workarounds such as the `\emph` in the title field, or those comments added to the `address` field).

Then [**`apacite`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/apacite) might work as wished.

However, `apacite`'s default behavior adds an extra year-label in order to disambiguate entries with the same year; to override that, we must redefine `\theBibCnt` (something like `\renewcommand{\theBibCnt}{}` should work).

See the following MWEs:

### With `apacite`'s default behavior (*with* extra year labels)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Waltzsy2006explicit,
  author = {Waltz, C},
  title = {Explicit Attitude Assessments},
  crossref = {Congress},
  year = {2006},
  month = {November},
  pages = {100-110},
}
@inproceedings{Waltzsy2006implicit,
  author = {Waltz, C},
  title = {Implicit Attitude Assessments},
  crossref = {Congress},
  year = {2006},
  month = {November},
  pages = {110-120},
}
@proceedings{Congress,
  booktitle = {{Seventh International Congress on Attittude Assessments, November 15--18, Chicago, IL, USA}},
  title = {{Seventh International Congress on Attittude Assessments, November 15--18, Chicago, IL, USA}},
  address = {Chicago},
  publisher = {The Congress Press},
  year = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\cite{Waltzsy2006implicit}, \cite{Waltzsy2006explicit}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: apacite's default behavior]

### Changing `apacite` (*without* extra year labels)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Waltzsy2006explicit,
  author = {Waltz, C},
  title = {Explicit Attitude Assessments},
  crossref = {Congress},
  year = {2006},
  month = {November},
  pages = {100-110},
}
@inproceedings{Waltzsy2006implicit,
  author = {Waltz, C},
  title = {Implicit Attitude Assessments},
  crossref = {Congress},
  year = {2006},
  month = {November},
  pages = {110-120},
}
@proceedings{Congress,
  booktitle = {{Seventh International Congress on Attittude Assessments, November 15--18, Chicago, IL, USA}},
  title = {{Seventh International Congress on Attittude Assessments, November 15--18, Chicago, IL, USA}},
  address = {Chicago},
  publisher = {The Congress Press},
  year = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\renewcommand{\theBibCnt}{}
\begin{document}
\cite{Waltzsy2006implicit}, \cite{Waltzsy2006explicit}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: apacite without extrayear]